# appendChild function that could be called multiple times and make multiple elements with content in it

Tags: javascript, function, callback, appendchild

How am I supposed to convert this append child code to function, so I could make my code more readable and shorter? Also would it be possible to one of those childrens append another children, also created with this function?

```js
let infoDiv = document.createElement("div");
infoDiv.classList.add("fullEventInfo");
classes.appendChild(infoDiv);

let titleTypeDiv = document.createElement("div");
titleTypeDiv.classList.add("titleType");
infoDiv.appendChild(titleTypeDiv);
```

Comment: I’m not really sure where the difficulty is to write a function that generalizes what this code is doing (twice). The function would likely take three parameters corresponding to the three pieces that are different between the two parts of the snippet. _“Also would it be possible to one of those childrens append another children”_ — Isn’t that what the code is already doing, e.g. at `infoDiv.appendChild(titleTypeDiv)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
function createElement(type, props, ...children) {
  const elem = document.createElement(type);

  if(props)
    Object.assign(elem, props);

  for(let child of children) {
    if(typeof child === "string")
      elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(child))
    else
      elem.appendChild(child)
  }

  return elem;
}
```

So:

```js
let elem = createElement("div", { className: "test" }, createElement("p", {}, "hello world !!!"));
```

This renders as:

```html
<div class="test">
  <p>hello world !!!</p>
</div>
```